# Get Key Name Dynamic in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have below array how can I get key name in loop?

```
$value = stdClass Object ( [autoincrement_id] => 1 [ID] => 1 [State] => Gujarat [Country] => India [Company] => Company1 [rowid] => 1 )

echo $value->State; // I Get Gujarat
```

But how i get Key name dynamic, i have loop and i don't know my key name. What i can write in loop so i get key name in loop?

```
echo $value->[????] // Which i write here to i get value of state?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - print all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034530/php-print-all-properties-of-an-object)

Comment: `foreach($value as $key=>$val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with foreach:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    // similar results
    echo $values->{$key};
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: What is `$values`? I suppose OP asks about object. If object does not implement `Iterator` you cannot iterate over it.

Comment: Object properties can be iterate. But only if the properties are public. Protected and private properties are hidden.